# Can we get Root View in an xml layout in Databinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Something like the following:

`android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClick(rootView)}"`

Source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="Presenter" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClick(rootView)}"
            android:text="abcde" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tytyt" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `rootView`? You can get view object of layout by using `binding.getRoot()`. Let me know if you are not looking for this.

Comment: I want to get it from xml, not from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get perticular view by its ID

```
android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClick(viewId)}"
```

In your case you can do

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onClick(parentView)}"
        android:text="abcde" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tytyt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and your onClick will be

```
public void onClick(View view) or public void onClick(LinearLayout layout)
{

}
```

Comment: I recall trying this some time ago and it didn't work, however it seems to work now, so your answer should be marked accepted and used as it is closer to what the thread starter originally desired.Sorry for misleading.

Comment: Thats alright :) As there is always multiple approach to reach the destination.

Comment: Indeed, however yours is more clear as the logic for providing the root won't be necessary. It's the way forward ! Cheers